# Execute methods one by one in Angular and RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
this.userClient.getUser(userName)
.pipe(
    concatMap(
        user => { 
            this.user = user;
            return this.userClient.setStatus(this.user.id, 'banned');
        }
    ),
    concatMap(
        user => {
            //set property...
            return this.userClient.deleteImg(user.img);
        }
    ),
    mergeMap(
        user => {
            this.user = user;
            return this.userClient.setGroup(user.id, 'test');
        }
    )
)
.subscribe(
    user => {
        //actions
    },
    error => ...
)
```

I would like my methods to be turned on one by one, not all at once. how can I do this? forkJoin is the only way out?

Comment: You can get away with using `switchMap` for all 3 of them.

Comment: `forkJoin` will not make it one by one but all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the first switchMap, but then return a concat. The concat will sequence the three items you wish for. Concat waits until one is done, then does the next, and so on.

You can find more info on `concat` on the [RxjS Concat docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat)

```
this.userClient.getUser(userName)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(
      user => { 
        this.user = user;
        return concat(
            this.userClient.setStatus(this.user.id, 'banned'),
            this.userClient.deleteImg(user.img),
            this.userClient.setGroup(user.id, 'test')
        );
    }
)
)
.subscribe(
  ([user]) => {
    //actions
  },
  error => ...
)
```

On [an episode of the Angular Show](https://open.spotify.com/episode/6YSwV2WqiZddt2F16jTQ1M) they described some of these **Higher Order Mapping Operators**. It may help understand how these work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `switchMap`

```
this.userClient.getUser(userName)
.pipe(
    switchMap(
        user => { 
            this.user = user;
            return this.userClient.setStatus(this.user.id, 'banned');
        }
    ),
    switchMap(
        user => {
            //set property...
            return this.userClient.deleteImg(user.img);
        }
    ),
    switchMap(
        user => {
            this.user = user;
            return this.userClient.setGroup(user.id, 'test');
        }
    )
)
.subscribe(
    user => {
        //actions
    },
    error => ...
)
```